# Does indexedDB have anything to do with the DOM?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I would guess no, it is a window property and has no dependecies on the DOM.

Why then in this net plus tutorial is its detection tied to the DOM content loaded event?

Is this just thoughtless boiler plate?

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/working-with-indexeddb/

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/working-with-indexeddb/#comment-1111537813

Comment: I posted that question too , which he did not answer.  He said he's waiting for the "page" ( actually the DOM ) to load, but as I stated, I don't see the relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IndexedDB has nothing to do with DOM. You don't need to wait anything. You can use in head as well.

The only thing is it need `window` instance or origin for security and quota management. IndexedDB API, however, still use DOM convention such as event handling and error.